# simple implication question

Tags: logic

if $q \in Q$ $\Rightarrow$ $q^2\neq 2$ Why is this implication false?

Thanks

Comment: This implication is not false: it is true.

Comment: Thats what i thought

Comment: @James  the implication is true. The implication written by mfl is true as well (in classical logic).

Comment: my lecturer told me so i thought it best to ask

Comment: There is no rational number whose square is equal to $2$.  For reason why search "*why is $\sqrt{2}$ irrational?*"  There are many proofs, some dating back several thousand years to the ancient Greeks.

Comment: Minor correction: several is  *a couple* in this context.